# How to Cancel auto-saved editing on Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive

I am a member of some networking group. Over ten members share different documents and edit from their places. What I found confusing is once I pressed a button on my keyboard by mistake and later deleted it, but at the top of the document I saw a message that I edited it for the last modification, whereas I had not brought any change.

Other members may get confused at where I have modified. So, is there any way to cancel such an accidental editing by restoring the previous editing?

Answer (score 3):

Google Documents changes are typically batched into groups. I'm not 100% sure what the criteria is, but small changes within the span of a few minutes should all be grouped together.

If you're looking for a way to see both **if** and **how** you've changed the document's history, then go to `File` > `See revision history`

You can also get there by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>

In this history just click on the entry that you want to view and click `Restore this version`

To see even more detailed revisions (not grouped by time) - then open the Revision history and click on `Show more detailed revisions` at the bottom of the menu.

*Edit: Based on the question in the title you might also be looking for a way to disable autosaving. There is no way to disable auto-saving, but [based on another Webapps answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15702/how-to-disable-auto-save-in-google-docs) there is a clever workaround:

> After you login to Google Docs and are looking at your list of
>   documents, hover your mouse over the document in question. You should
>   see an 'Actions' dropdown appear to the right. If you click on that
>   you should be given the option to 'download' the file.
>
> Now you can work on your document locally on your office computer and
>   when you are done for the day just upload it back to Google Docs. :)